# Why can't I reinstall formerly purchased App (Mindapp)?

Tags: apps, store

I found that the app "Mindapp" disappeared from the Windows store and my library. On iphone/ipad I am used to that I can still reinstall an App even if the App gets deleted from the store.

The app is still available in google cache: <s>https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:JRKOmkGvenkJ:https://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/store/p/mindapp/9nblggh5zbdc%3Focid%3Dmsfe_edumktg_apps_oo_edu+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&lr=lang_de%7Clang_en&client=firefox-b</s>

28.8.2017 new link https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:TpKKv6ELoJYJ:https://www.microsoft.com/pt-mz/store/p/mindapp/9nblggh5zbdc+&cd=7&hl=en&ct=clnk&lr=lang_de%7Clang_en&client=firefox-b-ab
[image: Screenshot of google cache of Mindapp Application from Windows Store]

Can anyone shed some light on this problem, that Apps can be removed from the Windows store and should you reinstall your phone, you may not be able to reinstall them? Is there a way to backup Apps and reinstall without the use of the Windows store?

Comment: That link to the google cache is reporting 404 for me